# Mathematica .m file can not open in Ubuntu

Tags: packages, ubuntu

My operating system is Ubuntu. I add some new .m file to /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/AddOns/Packages/ and then call for it in Mathematica, but failed with the message Get::noopen: "Cannot open !(\"Qdensity.m\").".

What should I do to make it work?

Comment: you probably have no read access? Maybe it is better to put the file in $UserBaseDirectory

Comment: @RolfMertig What system on your computer? I can make it work in Windows but not in Ubuntu. And I do not know what is $UserBaseDirectory. You may take your Mathematica for example. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `In[1]:= $UserBaseDirectory
Out[1]= /home/rolfm/.Mathematica` Please read the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/$UserBaseDirectory.html)

Comment: Thanks! But in which folder?  Applications?

Comment: Yes, or Autoload.

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot! Can you tell why it works? By the way, you'd better give a answer such that I can choose it as the best answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually *Mathematica* under Linux is installed as root. Therefore normal users do not have wite permission to `/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/AddOns/` . This is why you see that message you mentioned. 
While in principle you could do something like `chown -R eden:eden /usr/local/Wolfram` , this is neither encouraged nor advisable. 
Instead, as mentioned in the documentation of *Mathematca*, you put user-packages into the `Applications` or `Autoload` directory inside either `$UserBaseDirectory` or `$BaseDirectory`.

However all you really need to do is to put a package somewhere in a directory which is on `$Path`. I.e. just like `MemberQ[$Path, FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications"}]]` gives `True`, so should `MemberQ[$Path,"/opt/mpackdir"]`, which you can easily achieve by something like `If[!MemberQ[$Path, "/opt/mydir"],AppendTo[$Path,"/opt/mydir"]`.

So all is really easy and clear.